# How do I pass a variable to a handlebars helper?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to implement a simple "if-equal" helper in handlebars, like so:

```js
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function(val1, val2, options) {
    return (val1 == val2) ? options.fn(this) : '';
});
```

And use it like so (let's assume the foo variable is set to "bar"):

```
{{#ifequal foo "bar"}} show something {{/ifequal}}
```

The problem is, when val1 is passed in, it's passed in as the string "foo", and not the actual value of the foo variable. In my debugger, I can verify that this[val1] is in fact set to the expected value of the foo variable.

Does Ember somehow alter the behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` just passes strings in. There is a `registerBoundHelper` being worked on, but in your case this should work.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function(val1, val2, options) {
   return (this.get(val1) == val2) ? options.fn(this) : '';
});
```

Comment: This seems so wrong. Are you telling me you cant do something like `<p>The array controller has {{length}}{{pluralize length "object"}} in it's content`

Comment: @Intentss you can now. Both the string and the values are available in the `registerBoundHelper` method